# Using Chat-bots to understand API for speeding development process?

Tags: machine-learning, references, natural-language

I am thinking about working on Question-Answering/Chat-bot problem in the context of software development.

Problem : In any software development work one needs to go through the reference guide for the APIs to understand what function to call for different purposes, which is a very irritating and time consuming process.

Solution : Have a chat-bot to which user can describe his task in natural language and bot then analyses the reference guide to provide useful guidance about related functions that would be needed to accomplish the task

What I am looking for is reference material related to such task directly or indirectly. I have done my googling on it and there are huge number of "seemingly" related material available.

So if you have done some work in this field (I don't mean taking IBM Watson and tailoring it, but core ML stuff as I want to do this from scratch), can you share some good reference literature/git-hub code that according to you may be relevant specifically to the problem mentioned above.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: Nope , seems like an unattacked problem so far. Scarcity of any direct literature that addresses this.